# Post Google Forms to a MySQL database?

Tags: php, mysql, post, google-apps-script, google-forms

I've had a look around the net, google etc. i can't decipher wether it is possible to post google form data to both a google doc **and** to a database where the rest of my website is running?

The reason for this is so i can allow people with a Google Account to complete large forms or surveys that i can build on the fly nice and easily.

Thank you for any enlightening responses

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes it is possible with Google Apps Script

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/jdbc

Comment: Thanks! Was looking all over google docs for this at the time!