# Automatically sending Google Form responses to a local MySQL Database

Tags: mysql, google-forms

I'm trying to set up a automated system in our lab of archiving metadata information for some next-generation data.

Essentially I want to be able to send a Google Form link to my colleagues, have them enter their data, and when they click submit, have it automatically update a local MySQL database that is running on our main lab computer, so that we can query any information regarding samples we may need later on.

I've a few days trying to figure this out, and haven't really gotten anywhere. The main problems are these: I know you can JBDC Class to do this. However, I am not entirely (or at all) familiar with how a Google Apps Scripts code is supposed to be run, and I am having trouble connecting to our MySQL host (which I am also not familiar with). It's apparent that because I am running a localhost, I cannot actually use JBDC to connect to it, and I had no luck when I tried to grant all connections access to MySQL server by following the answers on this topic ([How to grant remote access permissions to mysql server for user?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6239131/how-to-grant-remote-access-permissions-to-mysql-server-for-user)).

I'm kind of at a loss, and it may just be that I simply don't have the knowledge to accomplish what I'd like to do. Can anyone suggest any step by step tutorials, youtube videos, or offer some advice?

Thanks.

EDIT: Post's i've already gone through:

[Post Google Forms to a MySQL database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17662914/post-google-forms-to-a-mysql-database?rq=1)

[Google Form output to remote MySQL database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28655570/google-form-output-to-remote-mysql-database?rq=1)

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/jdbc